# Confused by JavaScript array sort function method

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm very new to JavaScript and I have what is almost certainly an absurdly basic question about the array sorting method.  I've tried googling but I've come up empty.  Any help you may be able to offer would be gratefully appreciated.

Anyway, I'm trying to learn about how JavaScript manipulates arrays and I'm quite confused about the .sort method.  The training materials I have provide the following example:

```
var numbers = [3,1,2];
numbers.sort(function compareNumbers(current, next) {
    return current - next;
});
```

When I run this in the console I get this:

```
numbers = [1,2,3];
```

I just can't understand *why* this is happening.  What is JavaScript actually doing to reorder the numbers in this way?  Why is it returning `[1,2,3]` and not `[3,2,1]` or `[2,1,3]`?  What do the `(current, next)` parameters represent, and what are they being passed?

Apologies if this is a dumb question but I'm totally new to JavaScript.  Any explanations would be much appreciated (simpler the better!).

Cheers!

Comment: [MDN docs on `sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Please spend [more time researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/497418) before asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: the example that you have pasted is totally wrong. It should never be "current, next". It should be a, b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript Array.sort method is using quick sort algorithm.

If there is no callback function the array will be sorted in ascending order comparing items after converting them to strings. Therefore you always need to provide a callback method if you want to sort numbers.

One can provide a callback method with two parameters (a, b) to compare two items and tell the sort method how item A compares to item B.

The callback function is supposed to:
1. return 0 if both items are equal
2. return more then 0 if item A should be on the right of item B
3. return less then zero if item A should be on the left of item B

Comment: Ah, that's very helpful.  Cheers :-)